# Simple relational query in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Let's say I have the following tables:

```
      product              transaction
------------------     ------------------
| id |   name    |     | id |  product  |            
------------------     ------------------
| 1  | Product A |     | 1  |     2     |
| 2  | Product B |     | 2  |     3     |
| 3  | Product C |     | 3  |     2     |
------------------     ------------------
```

Now, let's say I want to make a listing of the `transaction` table, but I want to display product names instead of product IDs.

In raw SQL, I would do something like this:

```
SELECT product.name FROM transaction, product WHERE transaction.product = product.id
```

I'm having a hard time figuring out how this would be done using Rails' Active Record Query Interface. I'm sure this is trivial to you Rails experts out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
transaction.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN product ON transaction.id = product.id')
```

Comment: Got it. So you basically use SQL but in the context of `.joins`. Cool. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can also add ".Select("name, product")" at the end. Should work alright.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to solve it the "Rails way":

first: change column `product` in transactions to `product_id`, and table names should be in plural, otherwise you must add e.g. `set_table_name 'transaction'` in the models, you will miss a lot of Rails' futures if you don't change it.

add/change these models:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :transactions
end

class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
end
```

If you persist on using column name "product" you must change the `belongs_to` to:

```
  belongs_to :product, :foreign_key => 'product'
```

but that is kind of ugly

Finally, using this:

```
Transaction.includes(:product)
```

Or if you want only those who has a product

```
Transaction.joins(:product)
```

Note:
I don't remember exactly, but I think I had problems with using "transactions" as table name in some application. Somebody else perhaps knows about that.

Comment: Very cool. Thanks for this. I am trying to do things the "Rails way" as I learn, so this is very helpful.